# Honeycomb Calendar Access

Tags: android, calendar, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing an app, that inserts weekly reminders in the Android calendar. The application has been tested an can update the calendar on Android 2.3.* and 4.0 devices.

I am aware that Android 4.0 formalised the calendar provider API, and that in versions prior to this the solution was 'unofficial'. For this reason I have developed two implementations one for ICS and above, and one for versions before ICS.

My code works fine on Android 2.3.* and >= 4.0 devices. However,I am experiencing difficulties with Honeycomb tablets. With those I am getting a  'Failed to find provider info for calendar'.

Could anyone who knows please point out the differences between 2.3 and Honeycomb with respect to accessing the calendar so I can have my app working on Honeycomb?